# Python merge pdfs without compression

Tags: python, pdf

I want to merge a number of pdfs into one pdf using python, but the method I use right now seems to compress the output:

```
from pathlib import Path
import PyPDF2

merged_object = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()

for file_item in list_of_pdfs:
    if Path(file_item).suffix != '.pdf':
        file_item = f'{file_item}.pdf'
    merged_object.append(PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(str(file_item)))

merged_object.write(str(directory))
```

I haven't been able to find a way to merge pdfs compressionless, any solutions?

Comment: Strange... I tried you code with the files below:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.1/scipy-ref.pdf
https://riptutorial.com/Download/matplotlib.pdf
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pillow/stable/pillow.pdf

It resulted in a 13462055 Bytes output file which is even slightly bigger than the sum of each pdf taken individually which is 12577087 Bytes. I don't notice anything abnormal and I believe the slight increase is normal. Note: I use PyPDF2 version 1.26.0

Comment: @S_Bersier I just realized the compression occurred one step earlier, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use to work with [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and never noticed compression. The [`insert_pdf` method](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#insert-pdf-examples) is suitable to merge pdfs. You can try the following:

```
import fitz
from pathlib import Path

merged_object = fitz.open(list_of_pdfs.pop(0))

for file_item in list_of_pdfs:
  if Path(file_item).suffix != '.pdf':
      file_item = f'{file_item}.pdf'
  to_append = fitz.open(str(file_item))
  merged_object.insert_pdf(to_append)

merged_object.save(str(directory))
merged_object.close();
```

Comment: I will give it a shot tomorrow, thanks

Comment: The original method also works, the mistake was on my end, not PyPDF2